# Java Swing drawImage sometimes slow in XORMode

Tags: java, swing, imageicon, drawimage

I have extended ImageIcon to colorize my icons for different purposes as needed.
I've tried quite a lot now, but when resizing the window it needs > 3 sec. to repaint about 60 32x32 Icons. 
First off, this only happens if I color them in XOR Mode. If I leave them as they are it's a matter of milliseconds. 
I tried converting the images to a better format with GraphicsConfiguaration.createCompatibleImage but that didn't help.
Now a strange thing: if I draw onto the component.getGraphics instead to the Graphics provided in the paintIcon method, it does so lightning fast even in XOR Mode, but only shows it in a short flicker until it gets overdrawn.
I draw them by adding JButtons into a JPanel with a FlowLayout.
Anything else I can try?

**Slow:**

```
public synchronized void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {

    g.setXORMode(color);
    g.drawImage(getImage(), x, y, null);
}
```

**Fast but flickering:**

```
public synchronized void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    gr = c.getGraphics();
    gr.setXORMode(color);
    gr.drawImage(getImage(), x, y, null);
}
```

**Fast but without Xor**

```
public synchronized void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    g.drawImage(getImage(), x, y, null);
}
```

Edit:
Found a **solution** now with a combination of a BufferedImage and AlphaComposite:

```
    public synchronized void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    int w = getIconWidth();
    int h = getIconHeight();
    BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D bg2 = bimage.createGraphics();
    bg2.setColor(co);
    bg2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    bg2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.DST_IN));
    bg2.drawImage(getImage(),0,0,null);
    bg2.dispose();

    g.drawImage(bimage,0,0,null);

    return;
}
```

Leaving the question open for some hours to see if someone comes up with a better solution though.

Comment: You could try creating a compatible but off-screen `BufferedImage`, paint your icon onto that with XOR and then just paint the resulting image to `g` using normal mode.

Comment: The first example is changing under underlying `Graphics` context which will effect everything else that is using it.  The second one is not disposing of the copy of the `Graphics` context, which is likely to cause a memory leak.  Have you considered using `AlphaComposite` instead?

Comment: In the first I set Graphics back to paint mode and in the 2nd I disposed it, but left that out for clarity. I'm currently trying haraldK's suggestion, which seems to help but is quite a lot of overhead. I will have a look into AlphaComposite afterwards.

Comment: Also consider a `BufferedImageOp`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A230513+BufferedImageOp).

Comment: I wonder if i can do it without buffering an extra image. The AlphaComposite approach looks promising, though i tried to DST_OUT the Icon (Its a black content filled one) and then DST_OVER a filled, colored rect, but that didn't work. Since i have not that much experience with AlphaComposites I'm doing some trial and error here, but maybe someone can help?